# How to add one time title in controller with Codeigniter and work everywhere?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new in codeigniter, i have a problem in codeigniter.
Please help me.
For examaple i have a controller.
Controller contain many method(function). Now my question is how to add title only one time and work evrywhere where return the title.
I don't know is it possible or not.

If you have any idea please tell me.

```
function home() 
{
$data['title'] = "Home"; 
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('home');
$this->load->view('footer');
}

function about() 
{
$data['title'] = "About";
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('about');
$this->load->view('footer');
 }

function contact() 
{
$data['title'] = "Contact";
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('contact');
$this->load->view('footer');
}

function profile() 
{
$data['title'] = "Profile";
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('profile');
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In your code, all the methods are setting different titles? How would you be able to set that "one time"? Currently, you're adding it to a undefined array that you're not doing anything with.

Answer (score 0):

application =>config =>constants.php

in constants.php define title

> > define('TITLE', 'mytitle');
>
> echo TITLE;

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it thru

```
$data['title'] = "Home"; 
$this->load->view('header', $data);
```

where you can access it in view

```
echo $title
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps to add title through the controller.

1. Add a title in the controller

   ```
   // Controller
   function home() 
   {
     $data['title'] = "Home"; 
     // Pass data array to header view.
     $this->load->view('header',$data);
     $this->load->view('home');
     $this->load->view('footer');
   }
   ```
2. Display title  in the header page

   ```
   // Header page title code
   <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define this in the construct of that class

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->data['current'] = $this->router->fetch_method();
}
```

Here is [link](https://puneetk.com/codeigniter-get-controller-or-method-name) to a tutorial

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP asks about setting the title, while this would simply get the method name for the current route callback. The title and the method name doesn't always need to be the same.